# How to remove models from django?

Tags: django

In Django how do you remove models that you have synced into the database?

For example in Django tutorial page had this following code

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
```

Then I used `python manage.py sql polls` and `python manage.py sql choice`  to create the tables into the database. But what if I did something wrong and don't want that model any more. What's the syntax to remove it?

Comment: For people ending up here: In contemporary versions of Django ([>1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/1.7/#schema-migrations)), this is taken care of automatically when you make migrations and run them. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#workflow): "Django can create migrations for you. Make changes to your models - say, add a field and **remove a model** - and then run makemigrations: ...". Also see linked questions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no syntax. Django doesn't removes tables or columns. You have to manually change your database or use a migration tool like South.

If you justing playing around with tutorial the easier way is to delete your sqlite database file and run a sync again.

Comment: @starcorn Try django-admin.py flush

Comment: As update to the current version 1.11 `python manage.py migrate yourapp zero` will undo your migration

Comment: @Sarit I think that the "zero" was always there, at least I could find references to it on Django 1.7. But anyway, this question doesn't make sense anymore since the syncdb command was deprecated and removed from Django.

Answer (score 30):

If you don't want to delete and re-sync your current database, the best way is to drop the table from your model manually:

```
$ python manage.py dbshell

> (Inside the DB shell)
> DROP TABLE {app-name}_{model-name};
```

Comment: Now manage.py migrate complains that the original table no longer exists.

Answer (score 21):

Why not simply try deleting the models from your models.py file? When you run

`python manage.py makemigrations`

the migrations file should be updated with the deleted models.

Comment: thanks. this makes sure it puts multiple table deleted with foreign keys in order

Comment: after doing python manage.py makemigrations, then do python manage.py migrate to remove the model from the database

Answer (score 4):

The most easiest solution is to just delete your model from models.py and run

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

(Note: Remove the model from everywhere where you have imported it like admin.py, views.py, or any other file where you have imported it)

Answer (score 3):

Commenting out the class that defines the model did it for me. Once I had done it and ran `python manage.py makemigrations`,
I got this as response:
`- Delete model MyModel`.
Checked afterwards with a DB Browser and it was actually removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing issue to update changes onto DB so you can directly run this command.

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a simpler method, by sheer experimentation. Even after deleting tables, Django was not making the migrations, so I did the following:

Simply delete the files created in your myapp->migrations directory, making sure that you do not delete the **init**.py and **pycache**

1. Starting from 001initial.py and downwards delete the files.
2. Run python manage.py makemigrations
3. Run python manage.py migrate

-M

Comment: Do NOT do this in PRODUCTION. The above instructions are for experimental DEV sandboxes only

Answer (score 0):

Django’s database handling through `syncdb` is purely additive: any new models will be added, but deleted models will not be deleted and modified models will not be modified.

If you do not have any data you want to preserve, you are fine just dropping and recreating the database: if you have anything you want to preserve, or even if you *intend* to have anything you want to preserve, I cannot advise you strongly enough to **use a migration tool**: [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) has been the de facto standard for every project I’ve worked on.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Migration command handle Model(database) you can do following steps.

First type

**python manage.py makemigrations app_name** # it will restructure your model

then type

**python manage.py migrate app_name** # it will apply to restructure your database.

**Example**:
I had Posts and PostDetail model,
later on, I wanted to remove PostDetail model and some fields(columns) from Posts model too.

I simply run migrations and migrate commands,checked in Mysql Database. It worked fine.

Hope it will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

> Weather you’re removing a single model or a full app, you should first
> remove the desired models from the models.py file.
>
> Moreover, you have to make sure that no other file imports these
> models or uses them (admin.py, views.py, etc).
>
> Next, run South or migrate your database to properly delete these
> models from your database.

Check the source of this information on the link below:

http://www.marinamele.com/how-to-correctly-remove-a-model-or-app-in-django

Answer (score 0):

1. Comment out the class you want to delete in `models.py`.
2. Comment out any other references to the model e.g. in `admin.py`.
3. Run the following commands in terminal:

   - `python manage.py makemigrations <your_app>`
   - `python manage.py migrate`

This should remove the related table from the database.